# Graphene Django without Django Model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, graphene-python

I've successfully used Graphene-Django to successfully build several GraphQL calls.  In all of those cases I populated, in whole or in part, a Django model and then returned the records I populated.

Now I have a situation where I'd like to return some data that I don't wish to store in the Django model.  Is this possible to do with Graphene?

Robert

Comment: Since the data will not live in a database, where should they live? Fetched by an external resource? A permanent string or something? Give more details about your use case, please.

Comment: In one use case the data would come from an external server.  In another, the results would strictly be the result of logic, not a lookup from a Django DB table.

Comment: A colleague helped me find a solution.  I'll make it generic so that everyone can understand the approach.

Suppose you wanted a GraphQL query called "best_cities".  In your class Query you might create this:

best_cities = graphene.String(state_id=graphene.String())

Here you pass in a State Id and then logic will be used to generate a JSON string with the response.

Then below you just need to add this:

def resolve_best_cities(self, args, context, info):

In this function you add custom logic.  A Django Model is not used at all.

Comment: @Robert_LY In case I'd like to add a graphql mutation instead of a query without mapping to a Django model. Does this work equivalently?

Answer (score 5):

Robert_LY answered his own question perfectly in the comments, I'd just like to expand his solution.

My database-less model WordForm is generated automatically, without storing it in a database. I define it as a Django model as follows:

```
from django.db import models
class WordForm(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    attributes = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

In the schema I define the node and query like this:

```
class WordFormNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = WordForm
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )

class Query(AbstractType):
    word_forms = List(WordFormNode,query=String(),some_id=String())

    def resolve_word_forms(self, args, context, info):
        query= args['query']
        some_id = from_global_id(args['some_id'])[1]
        word_forms = []
        # some logic to make WordForm objects with
        # WordForm(value=value,attributes=attributes),
        # then append them to list word_forms
        return word_forms
```

You can pass as many arguments as you like to the List and access them in resolve_word_forms.

Comment: i really like this answer because it has the advantage of using the native model fields to generate graphql ones, but I get "graphql.error.located_error.GraphQLLocatedError: resolve_word_forms() got an unexpected keyword argument 'some_id'". I resolved this using the parameter format "(root, info, **kwargs)"

Answer (score 0):

When you map your Django model to a GraphQL, it create a new model with GraphQL object types from the introspection of the Django model.. 
And nothing prevent you to combine this model with with plain GraphQL objects types, or mapped from an other third party persistence model